# Probability of a pick of balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In $13$ balls we have:
$5$ Blue
$4$ Red
$4$ Green

We randomly select $6$ balls without replacement, what is the probability of having at least $1$ blue and at least $1$ red?

Also what is the probability of having at least $2$ blue and at least one red

---

So I understand how we could do at least $1$ of a single colour ($1$-prob of not getting that color) but I'm not sure how to go about it such that you have at least one of each. Unless you do

$[1-P($No Blue$)]*[1-P($No Red$)]$

But this seems incorrect

Comment: Familiar with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) combinatorical approach? Or even [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) would be more useful here.

Comment: I'm semi familiar with stars and bars. Although I'm not sure how it would apply without replacement?

Answer (score 1):

We use ideas of inclusion-exclusion. For the first part, note that the number of ways to select no blue ball is $\binom{4+4}{6}$. Similarly, the number of ways to select no red ball is $\binom{5+4}{6}$. Note that we cannot simply have $\binom{5+4+4}{6}-\binom{4+4}{6}-\binom{5+4}{6}$ in general since we are double counting the cases where we select no red and no blue balls. So we must adjust for selecting only green balls. In this problem, however, since $4<6$, there is nothing to adjust for; the cases of selecting no blue balls and no red balls are entirely disjoint. Hence the number of ways to select at least one of each is
$$\binom{5+4+4}{6}-\binom{4+4}{6}-\binom{5+4}{6}=1604.$$
For the second part, note that the number of ways to select exactly one blue ball is $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4+4}{6-1}$. Note that it is impossible to select one blue ball and and no red balls. You should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Okay, so say if I wanted something like 2 blue, 2 red and 1 green, would it be:

(5C2)(4C2)(4C1) = 240

Then I suppose the probability is just out of how many possible combos there are: 13C6 = 1716

Then the prob would be: 240/1716 ~ 0.14

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Or would it be (5C2)(4C2)(4C1)(8C1) (Because there is an extra ball to have in our hand of 6)