# Picking colored balls randomly.

Tags: probability, random, card-games

I created [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720067/probability-of-a-pick-of-balls) post yesterday but I have a further enquiry that I will post here.

In 13 balls we have: 5 Blue 4 Red 4 Green

*We randomly select 6 balls without replacement, what is the probability of having 2 blue, 2 red and 1 green? (The color of the last ball does not matter)*

---

I think that this could be done by taking:

${5 \choose 2}\times{4 \choose 2}\times{4 \choose 1}\times{8 \choose 1} = 1920$

as the total number of combinations that has 2 blue, 2 red and 1 green, then dividing by the total number of 6 hand combos ${13 \choose 6} = 1719$

Obviously there is an issue here as $\frac{1920}{1719}>1$, but I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: You are overcounting.  If, say, you have $6$ red balls then you count that selection $6$ times (as you have no way to know which of the $6$ is the "extra" one).

Comment: So are you saying that choose functions aren't necessary?

Comment: No, of course not.  Just that you can't do it this way.  Just break out the three cases for the extra ball.

Comment: So with the 8C1, I'm counting duplicate cases, and this is why I need to break it into the extra cases?

Comment: I see that I gave a bad example in my comment.  The three cases are $(3,2,1),(2,3,1),(2,2,2)$.  Your method counts each of the first two types three times, and it counts each of the third type twice.   That's hard to correct for, so it is best to just count each type separately.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for explaining. I was doing it as if they were, say, distinctly labelled or something. It's sort of why using the choose function here sort of confuses me, as say for the first one ${5 \choose 2}$, it doesn't matter which 2 since they are all the same.

Comment: I don't understand.  It's fine if you want to imagine that the balls are distinctly labeled, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Say the balls are labeled:  $b_1,\cdots, b_5, r_1,\cdots, r_4, g_1,\cdots, g_4$.  And say your selection contains $b_1,b_2,b_3$.  That selection gets counted three times, once with $b_1$ as the extra blue, once with $b_2$ as the extra blue, and once more with $b_3$ as the extra blue.

Comment: Sorry yes what I meant was as if the question detailed them as distinct hands, so like $b_{1}$ being different to $b_{2}$ and so on, so something like $(b_{1},{r_1})$ is different to $(b_{2},r_{1})$

Comment: Yes, of course we are assuming that the balls are different for the count.  If you assume that all balls of a single color are the same then the answer to the problem is $3$.

Comment: Right, I think I'm over complicating matters haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, with that hypergeometric distribution way of solving it, is that ${8}\choose{1}$. That would suggest, that there are 5+4+4+8 = 21 balls in total.
You could for example distinguish between the cases for the color of the last ball:
${5\choose 3} \cdot {4\choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 1} + {5\choose 2} \cdot {4\choose 3} \cdot {4 \choose 1} + {5\choose 2} \cdot {4\choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2}$

Comment: Okay, so there isn't a more general way? I'm still not entirely sure exactly why the ${8 \choose 1}$ doesn't work.

I pick 2 blue giving me 3 remaining.
I pick 2 red giving me 2 remaining.
I pick 1 green giving me 3 remaining. 
This gives me 8 left for the extra ball in my hand. Where is this flawed?

Comment: You pick 2 blue balls out of 5 blue balls. So the 5 blue balls are "used" now, giving you 8 remaining balls to choose from, not 11.

Comment: That's the train of thought I was going down I believe. Which is why I added the 8C1